# How to run Cyberfox 44.0, or is Software Updater broke?

Tags: 14.04, updates, lts

I cannot run Cyberfox 44.0 on 14.04 LTS, issues with libstdc++.so.6 version 3.4.21.  They say I have an older version.  I checked, and LTS is now 14.04.3, but Software Updater never asked me to go there from 14.04 LTS.  I had to set it to "All versions" and go to 15.whatever not LTS.  I hope I will like it!  Maybe that will run Cyberfox 44.0?

Has anyone gotten Cyberfox 44.0 running on an LTS version?  Any Ubuntu version?

Any idea why Software Updater does not consider 14.04.3 a new LTS version?

Comment: cyberfox seems to be windows only... so how are you running it?

Comment: Idk about cyberfox, but I do know that all the .3 means is that you have all the updates since 14.04 was initially released. It's called a "point release" so those downloading the lts don't have to wait for updates that have been released over the last year (or 3) since it was initially released. As far as the going to 15.x, you still have to start it manually, as it is about as intensive as upgrading windows 8 to 10 (but less painful).

Comment: Oh, and LTS only refers to longer support life (updates for 5 yrs instead of 9 months--useful in institutions). There's no other major difference between this and a "normal" release. Also, versions are labeled by the yr.mo released (14.04 was released in April 2014).

Comment: Just to clarify my first comment, 14.04.3 is, in fact, just 14.04 with all updates installed. (Think Windows 7, service pack 1 without all the bloat.)

Comment: Why are you using Cyberfox? Firefox for Ubuntu (or Linux in general) is already 64-bit. AFAIK, Windows is the only OS where they didn't make a 64-bit version yet, but it's in the works from what I've heard.

Answer (score 0):

CyberFox seems to have gone unsupported, so I let it and its bugs go and moved to Chrome, with an occasional visit to FireFox when it misbehaves.  Opera is nice, too.